# Why does MySQL not use the index from EXPLAIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, propel

I have a straight forward table which currently has ~10M rows.
Here is the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `train_run_messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `train_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `station_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `train_run_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `customer_station_track_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lateness_type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lateness_amount` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `lateness_code` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `info_text` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `lateness_amount` (`lateness_amount`),
  KEY `customer_timestamp` (`customer_id`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `trm_customer` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `trm_train` (`train_id`),
  KEY `trm_station` (`station_id`),
  KEY `trm_trainrun` (`train_run_id`),
  KEY `FI_trm_customer_station_tracks` (`customer_station_track_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_trm_customer_station_tracks` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_station_track_id`) REFERENCES `customer_station_tracks` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `trm_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `trm_station` FOREIGN KEY (`station_id`) REFERENCES `stations` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `trm_train` FOREIGN KEY (`train_id`) REFERENCES `trains` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `trm_trainrun` FOREIGN KEY (`train_run_id`) REFERENCES `train_runs` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9928724 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

We have lots of queries that filter by customer_id and timestamp so we have created a combined index for that.

Now I have this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM `train_run_messages` WHERE `customer_id` = '5' AND `timestamp` >= '2013-12-01 00:00:57' AND `timestamp` <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59' LIMIT 0, 100
```

On our current machine with ~10M entries this query takes ~16 seconds, which is way to long in my taste, since there is an index for queries like this.

So lets look at the output of explain for this query:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------------------    +--------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys                             | key                | key_len | ref   | rows       | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | train_run_messages | ref  | timestamp,customer_timestmap,trm_customer | customer_timestamp | 4       | const | 551405     | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

So MySQL is telling me that it would use the customer_timestamp index, fine! Why does the query still take ~16 seconds?
Since I don't always trust the MySQL query analyzer lets try it with a forced index:

```
SELECT * FROM `train_run_messages` USE INDEX (customer_timestamp) WHERE `customer_id` = '5' AND `timestamp` >= '2013-12-01 00:00:57' AND `timestamp` <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59' LIMIT 0, 100
```

Query Time: 0.079s!!

Me: puzzled!

So can anyone explain why MySQL is obviously not using the index that it says it would use from the EXPLAIN output? And is there any way to prove what index it really used when performing the real query?

Btw: Here is the output from the slow-log:

```
# Time: 131217 11:18:04
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 16.252878  Lock_time: 0.000168 Rows_sent: 100  Rows_examined: 9830711
SET timestamp=1387275484;
SELECT * FROM `train_run_messages` WHERE `customer_id` = '5' AND `timestamp` >= '2013-12-01 00:00:57' AND `timestamp` <= '2013-12-31 23:59:59' LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Alltough it does not specifically say that it is not using any index the Rows_examined suggests that it does a full tablescan.

So is this fixable without using USE INDEX? We are using Propel as ORM and there is currently no way to use MySQL-specific "USE INDEX" without manually writing the query.

**Edit:** 
Here is the output of EXPLAIN and USE INDEX:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | train_run_messages | range | customer_timestmap | customer_timestmap | 8       | NULL | 191264 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: How many different customer ids are there?

Comment: In the table train_run_messages there are only entries with customerId 5. (The system is designed for multi-customer, but there exists only one customer in this database)

Comment: In which case it will ignore the index on customer_id (rule of thumb, it seems if the index doesn't narrow the records down below about 1/3 then it will be ignored). However I would expect the time stamps to narrow it down more than that

Comment: Yes, timestamps narrow it down tremendously, the 10M records are more or less evenly distrubuted between 2009 and now.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has three candidate indexes

- (timestamp)
- (customer_id, timestamp)
- (customer_id)

and you are asking

```
`customer_id` = '5' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

The optimizer has choose `(customer_id, timestamp)` from statistics.

InnoDB Engine's optimizer depends on statistics which uses sampling when table is opend. default sampling reads 8 pages on index file.

So, **I suggest three things as follows**

1. increase `innodb_stats_sample_pages=64`.

   - Default value of innodb_stats_sample_pages is 8 pages.
   - refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_sample_pages
2. remove redandant index. following index is just fine. currently there is only customer_id = 5 (you said)

   - (timestamp)
   - (customer_id)
3. run `OPTIMIZE TABLE train_run_messages` to re-organize table.

   - this reduces table and index size and sometimes this makes optimizer smarter

Comment: Is my understanding of your answer correct, that it does not explain why the explain says it would use the (customer_id,timestamp) where in fact it will not use it when the query is executed? Has this to do with the statistics of the table and the innodb_stats_sample_pages?

Comment: @Shyru I think so. unlike Postgresql's histogram based stat., InnoDB depends on sampling and `innodb_stats_sample_pages` is the only way to accurate statistics. If histogram based stat., Postgresql will not use (customer_id, timestamp) he already know there is only 5 customer_id.

Comment: But why does EXPLAIN say that it would use the index customer_timestamp but in reality it is not using this index??

Comment: In my experence,  `FORCE INDEX()` forces use that index. I guess `USE INDEX` just hint not forces. Why don't you EXPLAIN with `USE INDEX` to figure out really uses given index. And what if using FORCE INDEX how long takes. BTW, It's 00:12 am here. I can't keep track.  Sorry.please, Let me know test result. I'm also doubt.

Comment: I tried the steps you outlined (but I did not delete the timestamp index as we need that for other queries) and it did not make any difference unfortunatly.
I also tried it with USE INDEX (timestamp) which also reduces the query time significantly (~0.06s) because we have only one customer_id. So if mysql would use ANY of the indexes it outputs in possible_keys from EXPLAIN it would go fast. I really do not understand this. :-(

Answer (score 0):

To me, the biggest thing it is failing on your wrapping the customer ID in quotes... such as = '5'.  By doing this, it cant use the customer/timestamp index because the customer Id needs to be converted to a string to match your '5' vs just = 5 and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not sure that is correct when comparing against a numeric column (it will perform the conversion only once), although it would be true if using an unquoted number to compare with a string column.

Comment: @Kickstart, the point is... if the indexed column is numeric, and its trying for whatever reason to convert the data column to string to match the = '5', it can't utilize the index as well, vs the actual query using  column = 5 (with same expected data type), no conversion or false interpretation going on to resolve the execution plan.

Comment: I believe it can (and certainly does when testing it quickly), as it only has to convert '5' to 5 once and can then use the index. This is an overhead but a tiny one and won't increase as the number of rows increases. The problem comes when comparing an unquoted 5 to a char column, where many different character values could be evaluated to a numeric 5. In this circumstance MySQL would have to convert every row to a numeric, hence not being able to use any index.

Comment: @Kickstart, correct.  When you are supplying an EQUALITY, I believe the engine is doing a "Hey... the user wants '5'".  Maybe this as a string includes "5", "50", "500", "528392", "532901289", etc. But will become a performance killer and ignore index capability.

Comment: @DRapp, i just executed the query with customer_id = 5 and the result was the same, ~16s query time, so I don't think it makes a difference here.